# Allow users to temporarily lock a remote branch in a GIT remote repository

Tags: git, github, locking, branch, temporary

Is there a way to allow users to temporarily lock a remote branch in the remote repository.
The function of is to avoid any merging in GIT that isn't Fast-Forward and to avoid conflicts (the constraint comes from the file type I am using). 
The method should be easy to lock and unlock, and users should be able to check the status of a branch somehow.

Comment: The general solution is to avoid a workflow that involves multiple users pushing directly to the same branch.

Comment: GitHub usually prefers forcing users to merge by creating pull requests, which must be reviewed by someone who then merges if the feature branch looks OK.  What is your current workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it yourself by writing a `pre-receive` hook that checks whether the locking condition is true or not for a specific branch and then allows the push or does not. How you set and display the locks is then up to you.

Other than that you could search for a Git repository hosting tool that has such a functionality built-in. But I cannot recommend one and this also would be off-topic on Stack Overflow.